# Как решить ошибку пула соединений к PostgreSql?

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, amazon-web-services, c#-8.0

сть PostgreSql на AWS. Коннекшн к ней делается через DbConnecrionFactory, что-то типа такого:

```
using (IDbConnection dbConnection = _dbConnectionFactory.NewNpgSqlConnection())
{
   // Something
}
```

Проблема в том, что при быстрых запросах вылетакт ошибка:

```
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 53300: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
```

Когда возникает ошибка? При быстрой перезагрузке сайта, при быстрых и частых (один за другим) переходах между страницами и подобных действиях

Может ли это быть связано с тем, что подключение к БД делает внутри using, а не, допустим, через какой-то GenericRepository внутри DI (Scoped)? Но при переходе между страницами делается только один запрос к БД, по этому количество запросов не должно меняться

Я думаю, что проблема может быть в одном из вариантов:

- В using'ах, которые используются для подключения к БД. Тут я больше
  склоняюсь к тому, что подключение к БД должно быть одно на весь http
  запрос, а не открываться отдельно для каждой операции
- В tria версии
  aws, на котором лежит БД. Там может быть ограничение по подключениям.
  Из-за того, что поступает много асинхронных запросов, забиваются все
  доступные подключения

Я запутался немного, поправьте, если ошибаюсь. Как мне решить эту проблему?

Comment: Какую версию NPGSQL вы используете. Если у вас нет задачи создать собственный пул соединений вам не нужно для каждого запроса создавать новое соединеие внутри блока using библиотека имеет собственный пул который вполне справляется с выделением простаивающих соединений без создания новых. Число соедиений в настройках пула библиотеки не должно превышать max_connections  настройки сервера а лучше быть его меньше если есть еще клиенты кроме вас.